# java 1.4 :how to insert multiple records in a database with one single hit using executeBatch?

Tags: java1.4, non-static, multiple-insert

i am reading records data from a file(records count can be up to thousands ).Now i want to insert each record in to database.I want to insert all of records in one hit to reduce performance hit. If i use addBatch(String sqlQuery ) on statment object,my sql query should be static .but in my case query will be non static.Please tell me possible solutions with best performance?

platform
java 1.4
sql server 2000.

Comment: Which DB are you refering to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_%28SQL%29)

A SQL feature (since SQL-92) is the use of row value constructors to insert multiple rows at a time in a single SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO ''TABLE'' (''column1'', [''column2, ... '']) 
VALUES (''value1a'', [''value1b, ...'']), 
       (''value2a'', [''value2b, ...'']), 
   ...
```

Comment: thanks.in this case,i will have to generate my sql query dynamically depending upon number of records.If there is some better solution,pls tell?

Comment: What error do you get? If I'm not wrong, MSSQL2000 should be SQL-92 compliant.